# Asymptotics through generating functions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, asymptotics

I am working on the asymptotics of a sequence and wanted to use the method of subtracted singularities (Darboux's method) for its generating function $f$. But it turns out that the function has $1$ as the singularity of order $1$ closest to the origin, the other singularities $(z_k)$, which are of order $k$, form a sequence converging to $1$. Thus I cannot find a neighbourhood of $1$ in which f behaves nicely, so Darboux does not work.
Any suggestions?

The function under consideration is
$
f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{k}z^{k}}{(2^{k}- 2^{k}z+z)^{k+1}}.
$
I tried to find some hints in the book by Flajolet & Sedgewick, but to no avail.

Comment: Adding a little context would be helpful.

Comment: did you check the book analytic combinatorics by flajolet and sedgewick? Flajolet spend a lot of effort on this kind of topics

Comment: The function under consideration isf(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{k}z^{k}}{(2^{k}- 2^{k}z+z)^{k+1}}